# Twilio custom call routing

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm looking to implement a custom call routing function for customers dialing a set of company phone numbers for a sales organization using Twilio.  Roughly speaking, I want to do something like the following:

- When an incoming call is received, based on the called number (i.e. which twilio number was dialed), lookup a different routing algorithm to decide how to route the call.
- Routing algorithm will have a number of specific steps, some of which would be like these:

  - lookup calling number in sales database, if already assigned then route call to assigned agent
  - lookup "agent on duty" in shift database, if agent is on-shift then route call to agent on duty
  - simultaneous ring multiple agents, first agent (if any) to pick up and "dial 1 to accept" gets connected to caller
  - dial a specific agent
  - fallback to voicemail
- For all these cases we want to "whisper" some caller information to the agent, and optionally present a challenge like "dial 1 to accept call" and gather a response before they are connected
- We also want to record calls (and preannounce "this call may be recorded..."

Looking at the Twilio API it seems like there might be a few different high-level approaches, for instance:

- Implement my own routing logic, and at each step (potentially) initiate a new twilio outbound call to the agent, present a challenge, gather digits, and connect to caller if agent accepts the call
- Implement Twilio Queues - probably place incoming caller in queue, step through routing table until we find an agent (or voicemail), and then pull caller out of queue and connect them
- Implement Twilio Queues + TaskRouter - as above, but use Task Router to specify my call routing algorithm.

There will not be a high volume of calls, so queuing wouldn't necessarily be my natural choice, but it is possible there might be a few simultaneous calls at any point.  I'm more thinking that queuing might be useful in that it's designed to handle this workflow - specifically accept call, play music/message/ring while we locate an agent, then connect the agent to the queued call.

In general would like some guidance on which path to take - not sure whether Task Router will be flexible enough to handle my call routing (i.e. can I use decision logic based on external database queries, API calls, etc to make task routing decisions).  Also, if I choose to do all of this myself (i.e. no queues, task router), then it wasn't clear to me how to "connect" two separate Twilio calls together (i.e. the inbound caller "call" and the outbound "call" to the agent) - do I need to create a twilio conference?

I'll be implementing this in python, but any references to similar implementations in any language would be helpful...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is well-formatted, but it's not a great fit for this site. SO focuses on narrow questions with specific answers instead of questions looking for broad guidance. For more information you can check out these [Help Center topics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Hi @cccc4983, just wondering what solution you went with for this? I seem to be faced with a similar problem at the moment regarding TaskRouter/Queues etc. for a low volume customer service team.